# Customized ISO will not install from a local kickstart on the installation CD

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, iso, kickstart, oracle-linux

I am trying to make a easy system install for an air-gapped system, I have to install Oracle Linux 6. I am adding the required kickstart file to CD and having the system install from that. In a VM to test the install it will accept the kickstart file then I will get a screen that says "Oracle Linux Server disc was not found in any of your CDROM drives. Please insert the Oracle Linux Server disc and press OK to retry."

All I did was mount the original ISO using:

```
mount -t iso9660 -o loop ./OracleLinux6.7.iso /tmp/TEMPISO
```

I copied the ISO to another directory so I can modify it

```
cp -pRf /tmp/TEMPISO/* /tmp/RWISO
```

I added my kickstart to the root of the cd

I then created a new ISO using this command:

```
mkisofs -r -T -J -V "AirGap Oracle Linux" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c\ 
isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
-o ./AIROracle.iso /tmp/RWISO
```

Why would the ISO not recognize that the repositories it would need are on the disk when they were not modified in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Check your boot config file to ensure that the LABEL option is correct. It should be found under `isolinux/`, and I know under Redhat it is called `isolinux/isolinux.cfg`, so it may be in the same place for Oracle Linux. You will need to modify the `append` line in the menu entry that you are using to kickstart to reflect the new label for the ISO. Additionally, for every space in your label you will need to substitute a `\x20`. Ultimately you will want your line to be something like `append [some boot options] inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=AirGap\x20Oracle\x20Linux [other boot options]`.

Comment: I'm assuming replacing the hd in inst.stage2=hd:... with cdrom would work if I was installing this from an actual CD not a usb?

Comment: No luck I had the boot options of isolinux.cfg as:
append initrd=initrd.img ks=cdrom:kickstart.cfg inst.stage2=cdrom:LABEL=AirGap\x20Oracle\x20Linux

Comment: @scholarhedge No, you'll need to use `hd:` even if you are booting from a CD.